# Using express-flash with EJS

Tags: node.js, view, ejs

I am  trying to adapt my error code so it can also handle other types of error like success

For example, when I render the sign up page

```
res.render('signup', {
errors: req.flash('errors')
});
```

Upon submitting the page, I am successfully sending the error flash with this code:

```
req.flash('errors', { msg: 'Account with that email address already exists.' });
```

and rendering it correctly with code.

```
<% if (errors.length > 0 ) { 
      for(var i=0; i < errors.length; i++) { %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-
    label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <%= errors[i].msg %>
    </div>
    <% } %>
        <% } %>
```

But in other instances I may have

```
req.flash('success', { msg: 'You have signed up successfully' });
```

How would you adapt the flash rendering block of code above so its suitable for both 'errors' and 'success'

I found some .pug code (not EJS) online (sahat hackathon-starter) that checks messages.errors but I am not sure where messages came from here!

```
if messages.errors
  .alert.alert-danger.fade.in
    button.close(type='button', data-dismiss='alert')
      i.fa.fa-times-circle-o
    for error in messages.errors
      div= error.msg
if messages.info
  .alert.alert-info.fade.in
    button.close(type='button', data-dismiss='alert')
      i.fa.fa-times-circle-o
    for info in messages.info
      div= info.msg
if messages.success
  .alert.alert-success.fade.in
    button.close(type='button', data-dismiss='alert')
      i.fa.fa-times-circle-o
    for success in messages.success
      div= success.msg
```

Thanks
Tony

Answer (score 0):

```
<% if (errors.length > 0 ) { 
    for(var i=0; i < errors.length; i++) { %>
  <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
      <%= errors[i].msg %>
  </div>
  <% } %>
      <% } %>


      <% if (success.length > 0 ) { 
        for(var i=0; i < success.length; i++) { %>
      <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
          <%= success[i].msg %>
      </div>
      <% } %>
          <% } %>
```